# Meteor deploy only half works, with no error messages

Tags: meteor

I'm using meteor deploy with a little test app, and I'm finding that it *sort of* works, but doesn't complain about anything in the logs, so I'm not sure what to do next.

For example, the home page doesn't render, while accounts-entry is able to render only the password field of the sign-up page (not the email one)! It's really quite weird.

I'm using the npm package to include a node module, however removing this doesn't seem to make any difference.

I'm not sure where to look next to debug this?

The code is here:
https://github.com/jimmytidey/observatory

The app is here: 
http://test_observatory.meteor.com

The logs look absolutely normal I think:

```
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:07:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:07:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /f1db89943c1358003f76977ed6df57e9adf2aaa2.css 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:07:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /537d85f650bdfb82439bc7d0c9e073f7b16684d6.js 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:07:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /f1db89943c1358003f76977ed6df57e9adf2aaa2.css 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:08:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /537d85f650bdfb82439bc7d0c9e073f7b16684d6.js 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:08:48 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:08:53 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /sign-in 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:08:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /sign-up 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:09:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:09:39 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /sign-up 46.65.36.129
[Sun Jan 05 2014 11:10:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /_GALAXY_ 46.65.36.129
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors seem to be on the client side, see the javascript console on your browser while visiting the page.

Errors with `meteor logs` only display the errors on the server side

The error seems to be a misspelling in `Template.coffee` for the word `Template`. (See https://github.com/jimmytidey/Observatory/blob/master/client/views/home/home.coffee#L1). I sent you a PR too.

This syntax error stops all of the code after it from running. This is why the router does not register its routes and nothing appears on the screen.

Silly typo ;-)

Comment: That's very helpful of you, thanks. I don't know why the browser console didn't occur to me! Still getting used to the client / server combination!

That typo comes from the bootstrap boilerplate project: 
https://github.com/BeDifferential/meteor-boilerplate/blob/master/client/views/home/home.coffee

Do you want to send them a pull request, or shall I?